# iOS SpriteKit make random moving of sprites and something like collision in space

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am new in SpriteKit, I know a little bit about `SKPhysicsBody`.

So first task is make all my screen like a "box" where all my sprites will move in random direction. So getting some of sides of my screen sprite has to change direction and move to anther position. I need something like a space collision, when sprites never stop.

I have found some of code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SpriteKit_Physics_Collisions/Introduction/Intro.html) that is connected to collision.

As I understood this part of code solve my first task:

```
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = edgeCategory;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

Another task direction and I suppose to use this one for all my sprites:

```
 SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveByX:randomX y:randomY duration:.1];   
 SKAction *repeatingAction = [SKAction repeatActionForever:moveAction];
```

But I think it can stuck when will try to detect colision, so then I need to change moveBy values again, but I supposed I just can initialize movement and then can leave this hard work for collision detection, so the question is how to initiate movement in this case?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @sangony, it is like when you shake something in the box and you can see that there are all object interact with each other and with a box I mean like in real life, but in the game box should be my screen where all objects move in different direction and after they have collision, then my object should change a direction, because of physic

Comment: I suggest you try: 1. Turn gravity off. 2) Move your nodes by using CGVector make. 3) Set restitution to 1.0 or close to that. That should give you a nice show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use forces and velocities instead of `SKActions` to move the sprites. You also have to set properties like `restitution`, `linearDamping` and `friction` to prevent the lost of speed on collision and movement.

```
sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
sprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
sprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
```

You can apply a random force to each `sprite`.

```
// randomX and randomY are two random numbers.
sprite.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake(randomX, randomY))
```

The sprite also needs a `categoryBitMask` and `collisionBitMask`. Each sprite can collide with each other or the edge.

```
sprite.categoryBitMask = spriteCategory
sprite.collisionBitMask = spriteCategory | edgeCategory
```

> **restitution** : This property is used to determine how much energy the physics body loses when it bounces off another object. The
>   property must be a value between 0.0 and 1.0. The default value is
>   0.2. Availability
>
> **friction** : The roughness of the surface of the physics body. This property is used to apply a frictional force to physics bodies in
>   contact with this physics body. The property must be a value between
>   0.0 and 1.0. The default value is 0.2.
>
> **linearDamping** :  A property that reduces the body’s linear velocity. This property is used to simulate fluid or air friction
>   forces on the body. The property must be a value between 0.0 and 1.0.
>   The default value is 0.1. If the value is 0.0, no linear damping is
>   applied to the object.

Comment: thanks for detail answer but I add everything but my object are in the same place. where I put it. so not action from sprite. I supposed it should moved. but it does not. here is my code.

Comment: I think the issue was that I have added applyForce method before adding sprite to scene.

Comment: also I noticed that the speeds are different depend on size of sprite, how to omit it?

Comment: try setting `sprite.physicsBody?.mass` to the same value.

Comment: mass does not work for me just if I adjust size it cause. also how can I make sprite to have rotation when collision detected